# Subquery on symfony form field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to generate a subquery to  populate  and form select in symfony but I get this error message

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 167 near 'd2 WHERE d2.distributor': Error: 'd2' is already defined.`

this is my code

```
-`>add('doctor', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Doctor::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {

                $subquery =  $er->createQueryBuilder('d2')
                    ->select('')
                    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Distributor', 'd2')
                    ->andWhere('d2.distributor = :distributor_subquery')
                    ->setParameter('distributor_subquery', $options['user']);

                $query =  $er->createQueryBuilder('d');
                $query->select('d')
                    ->where('d.distributor = :distributor')
                    ->setParameter('distributor', $options['user'])
                    ->orWhere($query->expr()->in('d.distributor', $subquery->getDQL()))
                    ->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('d.surname', 'ASC');

                return $query;
            },`
```

d2 alias is defined two times
 `$er->createQueryBuilder('d2')`

and

`->from('AppBundle\Entity\Distributor', 'd2')`

but in both functions the parameter is mandatory

I tried with

`$subquery =  $er->createQueryBuilder() ->select('') ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Distributor', 'd2') ->andWhere('d2.distributor = :distributor_subquery')`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please see the implementation of *EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder()* method: it already contains the *select* and *from* parts, it gets this information from it's entity class. So you can omit calling these methods, just add a *where* clause and bind params:

```
$subquery =  $er->createQueryBuilder('d2')
   ->andWhere('d2.distributor = :distributor_subquery')
   ->setParameter('distributor_subquery', $options['user']);
```

Comment: adding this code I get this error `Too few parameters: the query defines 2 parameters but you only bound 1`